# Clone the HDD of a broken PS3 to a new one

Tags: ps3

My PS3 recently died and I'm planning on getting a new one. Since I won't be able to use the data transfer utility couldn't I clone the HDD to the new PS3 HDD?

Comment: Don't think so, without getting the original unit fixed. If you have the Yellow Light of Death issue you can try heating the CPU to reflow some solder then use the data transfer utility

Answer (score 0):

No not really.  I hate to be the barer of bad news but because of Sony's obsessive security your data is probably lost.  There's no way to clone a PS3 drive or swap it over into another machine and have it work because it's pretty much bonded to the machine it came from.(at least from what I know)